# Drools Workbench docker container: Can't access the deployed server

Tags: docker, drools, kie-workbench, drools-kie-server, kie-wb

I tried delploying kie workbench using docker command `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -d --name drools-wb jboss/business-central-workbench-showcase:latest`  and kieserver using the docker command `docker run -p 8180:8080 -d --name kie-server --link drools-wb:kie-wb jboss/kie-server-showcase:latest`. I deployed a sample drl file to kie server using the business central. The screen image after deployment is as shown below.

[image: screen after deployment]

The remote server is given as 172.17.0.3:8080. But when I try to test the deployment file using Postman the server is not responding.The requests are getting timed out.The two endpoint services I tried to access are `http://172.17.0.3:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/`and `http://172.17.0.3:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/DemoRule_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. First of all Iam not understanding why is it getting deployed in some remote server and not localhost. Secondly why is it not getting accessible. I even tried the kie server container endpoint `http://localhost:8180/kie-server/services/rest/server/`. But none of this works. Can someone help me understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for myself. The service was available at `http://localhost:8180/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/instances/DemoRule_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. That's were the actual controller was available. Port 8080 was endpoint for wildfly server. The IP 172.17.0.3:8080 was related to docker container. It had nothing do with the controllers.